# How to get select element's value in react-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

So I'm trying to get a `select` element's value in reactjs, but just can't figure it out. The `this.refs.selectElement.getDOMNode().value` is always coming as `undefined`. All other controls on the form like `text` are working fine. Any ideas? Is it that you can't get the value of `select` element via `refs` and must use `onChange` event?

Updated:

```js
var TestSelectClass = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Router.Navigation],

  _handleDube: function(event) {
    DubeActionCreators.DubeTest({
      message: this.refs.message.getDOMNode().value,
      tax: this.refs.tax.getDOMNode().value,
      validity: this.refs.valid_for.getDOMNode().value
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <ReactBootstrap.ListGroup>
          <textarea
            className="form-control"
            rows="3"
            placeholder="Enter message"
            ref="message" >
          </textarea>
          <div className="input-group">
            <span className="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">$</span>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="10" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" ref="tax" />
          </div>
        <Input type="select" value="1" ref="valid_for">
          <option value="1">1 hour</option>
          <option value="2">1 day</option>
          <option value="2">5 days</option>
        </Input>
      </ReactBootstrap.ListGroup>
    )
  }
});
```

**Updated: Solution**
So, if anyone runs into something similar, apparently if you are using react-bootstrap you can't get to the `Input` element if you have wrapped it in a `ListGroup`. Either take it out from it or wrap all `Input` elements in a `<form>` tag. This solved my issue, thanks for all the help.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I've updated it with the code.

Comment: You nowhere set `ref="selectElement"`.

Comment: @julen That was just as an example. Please look at the code, I do set ref="valid_for" and then access it via this.refs.valid_for.getDOMNode().value

Comment: Why are you using "Input" instead of "select"?

Comment: That's because I'm using react-bootstrap.

Comment: Use `getInputDOMNode().value` not `getDOMNode().value`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I see you are using [react-bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/), which includes a wrapper around regular input elements.

In this case you need to use the [`getInputDOMNode()`](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/f26e39f4f8fc5a1906c829d82d6ddb48c5dd422a/src/Input.jsx#L31-L33) wrapper function in order to get the underlying input's actual DOM element. But you can also use the [`getValue()`](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/f26e39f4f8fc5a1906c829d82d6ddb48c5dd422a/src/Input.jsx#L35-L49) convenience function that [react-bootstrap provides for Input elements](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#input).

So your `_handleDube` function should look like:

```
  _handleDube: function(event) {
    DubeActionCreators.DubeTest({
      message: this.refs.message.getInputDOMNode().value,
      tax: this.refs.tax.getInputDOMNode().value,
      validity: this.refs.valid_for.getValue()
    });
  },
```

See this JSFiddle for a complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/mnhm5j3g/1/

Comment: Doesn't work. The getInputDOMNode() is coming up as undefined.

Comment: It does work, I have added a JSFiddle to showcase an example.

Comment: You are right, it does work. However, for some reason it doesn't work in my app, I'm going to accept the answer as it's the correct one though. Thanks

Comment: We could help you if you post all the relevant code — you'll realize in the code you posted there's no clue where is the handler for `_handleDube` set.

Comment: The API changed in React, now the `getDOMNode()` above should read something like `React.findDOMNode(this.refs.message).value`.

Comment: The API has further changed. Now it reads `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.message)`

Comment: @AndyFaizan even more, since React 0.14 `this.refs.message` already contains the reference to the actual DOM element, making `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()` redundant.

Comment: react-bootstrap's API changed too. `getValue()` seems to be gone.

Comment: In React 15.2.1 `this.refs.message.value` seems to read the value.

Answer (score 51):

it's quite simple:

on the render method you should keep an eye on the `bind(this)`

```
<select onChange={this.yourChangeHandler.bind(this)}>
  <option value="-1" disabled>--</option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

and your handler is like:

```
yourChangeHandler(event){
  alert(event.target.value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot! :)

Comment: This is the best way of doing that.

Comment: For performance reasons, best to bind your callback in your component's constructor vs. inline like this.  Per the docs.

Answer (score 16):

Make a function handleChange(). Then, put it in your render() like this:

```
<Input type="select" value="1" ref="valid_for" onChange={this.handleChange}>
```

And the function in the component:

```
handleChange: function(e) {
  var val = e.target.value;
},
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing right now, but the question is can't we use refs at all for a select element?

Answer (score 6):

```
"react": "^15.0.2",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.29.3",
"react-dom": "^15.0.2",
```

under the env, ReactDOM.findDOMNode() works for me.

in render():

```
<FormControl name="username" ref="username"/>
```

in handler():

```
const username = findDOMNode(this.refs.username);
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked for me. I actually had to go through the DOM hierarchy to come up with a way to extract the value.
PS: I did **not** use `ReactBootstrap.ListGroup` in my code. Just the `Input` from React Bootstrap. Here is my code (ES6+).

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

getValueFromSelect(ref){
    var divDOMNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ref);
    /* the children in my case were a label and the select itself. 
       lastChild would point to the select child node*/
    var selectNode = divDOMNode.lastChild;
    return selectNode.options[selectNode.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

Dependencies:

```
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "0.28.1",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
```

Answer (score 1):

Refs as strings are [considered legacy and may be deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html). But it seems as if react-bootstrap components won't work with callback refs. I was working on this today to handle a search input.

```
class SearchBox extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange() {
    this.props.updateQuery(this._query.value);
  }

  render() {
    // ...
    <FormControl
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      ref={(c) => this._query = c} // should work but doesn't
      value={this.props.query}
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search" />
    // ...
  }
}
```

I wound up grabbing the change event and getting the value from it. This doesn't feel the "React way" or very current, but it works.

```
class SearchBox extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.updateQuery(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    // ...
    <FormControl
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      value={this.props.query}
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search" />
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is yet another easy way! if you use `<FormGroup>` component and set the `controlId` props, the inner DOM (`<input>`, ...) will get that `controlId` as its `id` attribute. for example:

```
<FormGroup controlId="myInputID">
  <ControlLabel>Text</ControlLabel>
  <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Enter text" />
</FormGroup>
```

Then you will have the value by calling `document.getElementById`:

```
var myInputValue = document.getElementById("myInputID").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are here like me using the latest `FormControl` component here's a solution I did:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class Blah extends Component {
    getSelectValue = () => {
        /* Here's the key solution */
        console.log(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.select).value)
    }

    render() {
        return
        <div> 
            <FormControl
            ref={select => { this.select = select }}
            componentClass="select"
            disabled={this.state.added}
            >
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </FormControl>
            <Button onclick={this.getSelectValue}>
                Get Select value
            </Button>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Would I be able to know why this answer was down voted initially? I'm really new to react, and I would like to know whether this is a proper implementation or not.

Comment: @NivedithaKarmegam same issue I've been having here at SO ever since I joined, people down-voting without giving an answer why is really a problem. Regarding your question whether it's a proper implementation, it depends, at the time of writing this answer works I'm not sure about the recent updates. So my personal philosophy is if it works and you don't need to bother updating your library and want to be productive then this approach is for you. Otherwise, `react-bootstrap` documentation is your best friend because even accepted answers here at SO gets stale as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Event Handler should be as below:

```
const changeLanguage = (event: any)=> {
  console.log('Selected Index : ', event.target.selectedIndex);
}
```

2. JSX should contain following:

```
<Form.Control as="select" onChange={(event)=>{changeLanguage(event)}}>                
  <option>English</option>
  <option>Marathi</option>
</Form.Control>
```

**Note:** This solution works with function components. For class components we need to change the syntax accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

:

Teniendo en cuenta que en la actualidad existe uso obsoleto de getDOMNode() y uso obsoleto de findDOMNode()

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'
```

.  &

```
const Componente1 = (props) => {
    let clave = document.getElementById('formSignupPassword').value
    console.log(clave)
    return (
        <>
            <Form>
                <Form.Group className="mb-2" controlId="formSignupPassword">
                    <Form.Label className="mb-0">Contraseña</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Registre una clave"
                    />
                </Form.Group>
            </Form>
        </>
    )
}
```

.  & .

```
const Componente2 = (props) => {
    let passwordText = React.createRef()
    let clave = passwordText.current.value
    console.log(clave)
    return (
        <>
            <Form>
                <Form.Group className="mb-2" controlId="formSignupPassword">
                    <Form.Label className="mb-0">Contraseña</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Registre una clave"
                        inputRef={passwordText}
                        // or Use
                        ref={passwordText}
                    />
                </Form.Group>
            </Form>
        </>
    )
}
```

. ={() =>} &  .

```
const Componente3 = (props) => {
    const [userEmail, setEmail] = React.useState(null)
    console.log(userEmail)
    return (
        <>
            <Form>
                <Form.Group className="mb-2" controlId="formSignupEmail">
                    <Form.Label className="mb-0">Email</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="email"
                        placeholder="Registre una cuenta de email valida"
                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </Form.Group>
            </Form>
        </>
    )
}
```